# What are the names for a light-duty hoist/pulley system components?

Tags: garage, storage

I'm planning to create a storage rack for tires in my garage, similar to [this one](http://www.team-integra.net/forum/blogs/morningz/386-diy-garage-wheel-tire-storage-rack.html):
[image]

Only that my garage has high ceilings, and I want to hang it way higher. It's not safe to climb up the ladder with big SUV wheels in hand, so I'm planning to install a simple system of two pulleys to help me raise and lower the wheels (Raise them one by one to the needed height, and then just pivot them into their place on the rack by hand).

So basically I need something like this bike lift, but only with one hook:
[image]

What are the proper names for the components of this system? I think I need one pulley with hook, and one pulley with a brake and a bracket to attach to the ceiling. I'm not asking for a product recommendation, I'm just asking for correct names for these things because using these terms I can't find anything.

A related question is, would it work to buy a bike rack like this, and only install one hook on it? It lists capacity of 100lbs, so should be enough for one tire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for something called a block and tackle. This is a rope and multiple pulley system that gives you a mechanical advantage over a single pulley making it much easier to hoist the tire into place.

You should consider mounting four hooks on the ceiling overhead so that the block and tackle can be moved to the position where the tire will be resting on the shelf. The upper "hook" could even be a bar or pipe affixed to the ceiling in such manner that the top securing point for the block and tackle can be slid back and forth so that it can be pushed into position before hoisting each tire.

Answer (score 2):

1. Buy the bike lift.
2. Install the two top plates close together.
3. Make up a bracket that connects the two lower pulleys together, and has a hook to hold the wheels.
4. Lift the wheels into place

[image]

<sup>*Make sure the wheels do not exceed the weight limit of the hoist, and use at your own risk.*</sup>